# How to get the binary and library folders' path in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Let's say that I am writing a Python program on Linux. And I want to run a binary manually-installed command called "foo" using its path. Usually this is in `/usr/bin/foo`. But on some distributions it's `/usr/local/bin/foo`. Some other distributions may change it too.

So my question is how to get something like `$BINARY_FOLDER_PATH` or `$LIBRARY_FOLDER_PATH` which would instantly give me whether it is "/usr/bin" or "/usr/local/bin/" or something else (PATH gives a lot of paths, I am looking for a single output option if it's there)? Also for libraries folder. How to know if it was `/usr/lib` or something else? In Python for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot. If you want to find a particular binary, your best bet is going to be searching the PATH variable. There is some [code on activestate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52224-find-a-file-given-a-search-path/) that does what you want.

Comment: Then how do people install their software? I have a Python binary file for example and I want to put it in /usr/bin when installing it. How do people do that? (of course I can use the absolute path, but I am talking about relative)

Comment: Most people install their software using a package manager of some sort. If you're on a linux box, that package manager might put your file into /bin or /usr/bin. If you're on a MacOS box, then *brew* might put it in one location, while *port* puts it in a different location. If you're on a network, an admin might put it on a shared volume.

Comment: Yes but I am talking about a Python script which has some data files. I have a glade file (interface builder `.ui` file) and I need to refer to it and include it relatively. How is that possible?

Comment: If you need a relative reference, try using the [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#__file__) predefined variable.